# How to lay these numbers out in LateX?

Tags: symbols

I cannot get the indents for the 3 and the 1, can someone help?

[image]

Comment: And you also forgot to add some code in the form of a minimal compilable document showing what you're doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done by a simple table, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{}cccccc@{}}
  6 & 5 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 3 \\
    & 3 & 2 & 2 \\
    &   & 1 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

The simplest, the best ...but what fun would do it with a tabular? `:)`

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newlength\digit
\def\h#1#2#3{{\parindent0pt\leavevmode%
\settowidth{\digit}{0}%
\hbox to\digit{{\vtop{%
\makebox[0pt][l]{#1}\\%
\makebox[0pt][l]{#2}\\%
\makebox[0pt][l]{#3}}}}}}

\begin{document} 

\h6~~\h53~\h521\h42~33  

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using a simple `tabbing` environment?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabbing}
 6\=55433\\
  \>3\=22\\
  \>\>1 
\end{tabbing}

\begin{tabbing}1\=2\=\kill
 655433\+\\
  322\+\\
  1 
\end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

[image]